# How to change url as a string in a var on a click?

Tags: jquery

I have this url:

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/?sfid=422&_sft_category=vodafone
```

And It should become:

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/
```

On a click I am trying:

```
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.hash = "http://www.example.com/xchanges/";
});
```

But it doesn't change the URL

Comment: There is no hash, or "ash" I can see.

Comment: Is the event listener triggered? Try adding an `alert` or something to check it.

Comment: is it not triggered with the click?

Comment: yes I am looking at that answer, the issue was with my confusion with the meaning of HASH and URL, which might created a duplicate

Comment: however, i need to change the whole URL

Answer (score 0):

The hash is meant to be a string, like this comments hash is `28015985` (the full URL being [How to change url as a string in a var on a click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015985/how-to-change-ash-as-a-string-in-a-var-on-a-click#28015985)).

Take a look at the following jsfiddle. It sets the hash to `#somehash`, then prints the current hash.

http://jsfiddle.net/t1ko1tny/1/

Comment: "*The hash is meant to be a string*". Yes, and `"http://www.example.com/xchanges/"` is a string.

Comment: ok ash was a typo in the question title.

Comment: exactly @Oriol thanks and I don't understand why my address isn't changing

Comment: So you want the hash to be `http://www.example.com/xchanges/`? So the full url to be `mydomain.com/mypage.html#http://www.example.com/xchanges/`

Comment: i need to only change the address with no other action needed. No page changes, no refresh, just the change of the address

Comment: to http://www.example.com/xchanges/ - I did set up a string in my code which said it

Comment: So you don't actually want to change the hash? Just the URL?

Comment: @rob.m So, do you want to replace all the URL? Or just the hash (the part after `#`)?

Comment: yes exactly, what is the diff between hash and url? thought that what ash was, the url. Sight*

Comment: The hash is the `#myhash` part of a URL, the URL is the full thing (including the hash).

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s8mv41b0/

```
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 window.open("http://www.example.com/xchanges/","_self");
});
```

Comment: that is changing, refreshing, the page. I simply want to change the url with no action

Comment: Hmmm, ok then I think you must use AJAX for that. I am not an expert yet when it comes to AJAX.